# Does the put method in Google's Bigquery client library utilize a streaming insert?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to know if the code below causes a streaming insert to occur for every value of `src` (assuming a slice of structs is passed for `src`)?

```golang
func (u *Inserter) Put(ctx context.Context, src interface{}) (err error) {
    ctx = trace.StartSpan(ctx, "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery.Inserter.Put")
    defer func() { trace.EndSpan(ctx, err) }()

    savers, err := valueSavers(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return u.putMulti(ctx, savers)
}
```

`Put` method can handle multiple objects or a single object but I'd like to avoid being charged for every single insert if that is indeed how the output of this method is billed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Put uses a StreamingInsert. If you go to the definition of [putMulti](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/inserter.go#L172), you'll see that it is calling Tabledata.InsertAll, which is the [method called for streaming](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll).

Notice that [streaming is charged by row inserted](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#streaming_pricing) not by request. So, it is the same to write, for example, 5 rows per "Put" than just one.

If your use case allows it, you should look at loading the data with a [loading job](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#hdr-Loading_and_Uploading), which is a free operation for bulk loading.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I shall see if I can implement a loading job and follow up